# Cannot connect to site using SPOMod

Tags: csom

I'm using SPOMOD and have used it in the past, but I think it might be broken forever. I'm getting the following error when trying to connect:

Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot contact web site
'https://domain.sharepoint.com/' or the web site does not support SharePoint Online credentials. The response
status code is 'Unauthorized'. The response headers are 'X-SharePointHealthScore=0,
SPRequestGuid=5aa8a59d-8092-2000-15b6-124fb12347a3, request-id=5aa8a59d-8092-2000-15b6-124fb12347a3,
X-MSDAVEXT_Error=917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+
and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically., MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices=16.0.0.5708,
X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff, X-MS-InvokeApp=1; RequireReadOnly, Content-Length=0, Content-Type=text/plain;
charset=utf-8, Date=Tue, 20 Sep 2016 16:06:01 GMT, P3P=CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI
TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI", Server=Microsoft-IIS/8.5, X-Powered-By=ASP.NET'."
At C:\Users\jfedorowicz\sharepoint\SPOMod.psm1:3209 char:3
+   $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException

---

Any idea?

Comment: Might want to look at the PnP Powershell module instead, https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell

Comment: That looks great and I'm going to check it out, but it doesn't look like it has the ability to edit existing List Column attributes, which is what I need to do. I'm trying to set a CSV worth of them to be optional as opposed to required.

Comment: I already answered it here - **https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224909/69297**

Comment: Answering questions from a year ago?