# ExecuteQuery Error When Trying to Do Anything

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, csom

I'm a global admin on my O365 tenant. I get the below error when I try to access anything:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot contact web site
'https://domain.sharepoint.com/' or the web site does not support SharePoint Online credentials. The response
status code is 'Unauthorized'. The response headers are 'X-SharePointHealthScore=0,
SPRequestGuid=664da69d-002a-2000-15b5-db84f0677cb9, request-id=664da69d-002a-2000-15b5-db84f0677cb9,
X-MSDAVEXT_Error=917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+
and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically., MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices=16.0.0.5708,
X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff, X-MS-InvokeApp=1; RequireReadOnly, Content-Length=0, Content-Type=text/plain;
charset=utf-8, Date=Thu, 22 Sep 2016 16:10:24 GMT, P3P=CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI
TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI", Server=Microsoft-IIS/8.5, X-Powered-By=ASP.NET'."
At line:1 char:1
+ $Context.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled` to **false**

```
Set-SPOTenant -LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled $False
```

And don't use `-credential` parameter at  `Connect-SPOService` , just type it as

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://deletethis.sharepoint.com
```

Then provide username and password , execute your code that should be now worked `without status code is 'Unauthorized'` !

Check also [Unable to access SharePoint Online with Powershell](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_manage/connect-sposervice-fails-unable-to-access/0aa6665b-c3d8-4138-92e4-6dfab2cbf038?auth=1)

Comment: So I dont think this worked. I want it set to False, not True...right? Anytime I try to run ExecuteQuery()...no matter what I'm doing....I get that error. It is supposed to be Tenant wide right? My error only points to my root site collection (see above) even though I'm running scripts on other ones.

Comment: the above solution to overcome status code is 'Unauthorized' ? are you tried to connect as I mentioned above ?!

Comment: It connects fine. It blocks me from pulling any data.

Comment: Dear @JoeFedorowicz if it connects properly why it get status code is 'Unauthorized' !!

Comment: That's what I'm asking dude

Comment: are you tried to connect via Connect-SPOService -Url https://harmelinmedia.sharepoint.com without -credential

Comment: Yes, but then I try to pull some data. When I get to ExecuteQuery(), it throws the above error

Comment: Is it occurs at all site or only this site

Comment: All sites that I've tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45777/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-joe-fedorowicz).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was related to this parameter was set to True -

> Command: **Get-SPOTenant**
>
> **LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled : False**

which should be :

> **LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled : True**
>
> Command: **Set-SPOTenant -LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled
>   $True**

**Note:** *You may be instantly able to see the newly changed value, but it takes about an hour to actually see the effect.*

Answer (score 0):

Once you have done the change at the Tenant level, it may take 24 hours for the change to be propagated.